# Implement a generic type for an interface's function property

Tags: typescript, interface

From redux-devtools-extension, I wanted to implement interface EnhancerOptions, which contains the following function property (or method or however it should be referred to when it comes to interfaces):

```
stateSanitizer?: <S>(state: S, index: number) => S;
```

the thing is, I wasn't able to provide the type for S (the state's shape, if you will), for instance something like this:

```
const options: EnhancerOptions = {
  stateSanitizer: (state: MyState, index: number) => state.data ? { ...state, data: '<<LONG_BLOB>>' } ? state
};
```

gives me the following error:

```
Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
Type 'S' is not assignable to type 'MyState'.ts(2322)
```

Is it actually possible to provide the type of S from the implementation, rather than at usage time, like in:

```
options.satetSanitizer<MyState>(state, index);
```

How should I go about implementing such interface since in order for it to be really useful, the function that stateSanitizer receives should operate according to the shape of my state, as you can see in *state.data*, since *data* would never exist on type **S**?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is want you need but you can specify `<S>` at the interface level like this:

```
type MyState = {
  data: any
}

type EnhancerOptions<S> = {
  stateSanitizer?: (state: S, index: number) => S;
}

const options: EnhancerOptions<MyState> = {
  stateSanitizer: (state: MyState, index: number) => state.data ? { ...state, data: '<<LONG_BLOB>>' } : state
};

const state: MyState = {
  data: '123'
}

options.stateSanitizer(state, 10)
```

Hope it helps or at least provide idea on how to find your actual solution.

Comment: Hi @kctang, that really is a good solution, the only thing is that that interface is defined within the redux-devtools-exension module/package, that's why I've been trying to make it work as it is...
If it's not possible, do you know how should I go about modifying such interface, since as I already mentioned, it comes out of the box with the package? should I just modify it from the package itself?